# c# Write DataTable Rows in txt File

Tags: c#, datatable

I have for like 40 rows on My `DataTable` Displayed in a `DataGridView`
i'm confused why my method Saves Only `One Row` in the `TextFile` :

```
    private void SaveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String outputFile;
        List<String> ListData = new List<String>();
        using (SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog())
        {
            sfd.Filter = "Txt File|*.Txt";
            if (sfd.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
                return;
            outputFile = sfd.FileName;
        }

        DataTable tb = pw.SavedInfo(User_info.UserID);

        for (int i = 0; i < tb.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
           ListData.Add("Name==> " + tb.Rows[i][1].ToString() + "  LastName ==> " + tb.Rows[i][2].ToString() + "  Email ==> " + tb.Rows[i][3].ToString() );

        }

        foreach (String s in ListData)
        {
            using (TextWriter Tw = new StreamWriter(outputFile))
            {
                Tw.WriteLine(s);
            }               
        }
    }
```

Did i missed something ? cause it was a really long day to keep being focused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the same `StreamWriter`:

```
using (TextWriter Tw = new StreamWriter(outputFile))
{
    foreach (String s in ListData)
    {
        Tw.WriteLine(s);             
    }
}
```

or use the [constructor that takes a boo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb(v=vs.110).aspx)l for "append":

```
foreach (String s in ListData)
{
    using (TextWriter Tw = new StreamWriter(outputFile, true))
    {
        Tw.WriteLine(s);
    }               
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
File.WriteAllLines(outputFile, lisData);
```

Use this to write in the file. [File.WriteAllLines Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92e05ft3(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I v used Foreach first then the TextWriter i had to use the textwriter before looping , but thanks sir!

Comment: this overload for `File.WriteAllLines(...)` takes and `IEnumerable<string>` so you wouldn't need the `foreach` or the `StreamWriter` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383693(v=vs.110).aspx